# QWebEngineView does not import JavaScript functions from online repositories

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt6, qwebengineview

I have created an html file for a tree diagram using the python package pyvis (version: 0.3.2). I would like to load this html file in a GUI using QWebEngineView of PyQT6 but I am getting the following error:

```
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: vis is not defined.
```

In the html file created, it contains some embedded JavaScript for importing 'vis' from an online repository which I suspect is not being executed.
One thing I'd like to point out is that I can load this html file on my web-browser (edge, google chrome). On google chrome, its console does say the following even though the file is loaded as intended:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis-network/9.1.2/dist/vis-network.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

Here is a simple version of the Python code for recreating the issue:

```
from pyvis.network import Network
import numpy as np
import os, sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


# Example dataset
dataset = [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]]
net = Network()

# Add nodes
nodes = list(set(np.concatenate(dataset)))
nodes_index = {}

for index, entry in enumerate(nodes):
    net.add_node(index, label=entry, shape="circle")
    nodes_index[entry] = index


# Add an edge with hover content
for entry in dataset:
    net.add_edge(
        nodes_index[entry[0]], nodes_index[entry[1]], title="Pi-Pi Occupancy = 10%"
    )

net.save_graph("tree_diagram.html")
path = os.sep.join([os.getcwd(), "tree_diagram.html"])
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)


class WebView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.window_layout)
        self.web = QWebEngineView()
        self.window_layout.addWidget(self.web)
        self.web.load(url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    page = WebView()
    page.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

And here is the html file created (if in case it is useful):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
            <script src="lib/bindings/utils.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis-network/9.1.2/dist/dist/vis-network.min.css" integrity="sha512-WgxfT5LWjfszlPHXRmBWHkV2eceiWTOBvrKCNbdgDYTHrT2AeLCGbF4sZlZw3UMN3WtL0tGUoIAKsu8mllg/XA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis-network/9.1.2/dist/vis-network.min.js" integrity="sha512-LnvoEWDFrqGHlHmDD2101OrLcbsfkrzoSpvtSQtxK3RMnRV0eOkhhBN2dXHKRrUU8p2DGRTk35n4O8nWSVe1mQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
                    
<center>
<h1></h1>
</center>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.js"> </script>-->
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>


        <center>
          <h1></h1>
        </center>
        <style type="text/css">

             #mynetwork {
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 600px;
                 background-color: #ffffff;
                 border: 1px solid lightgray;
                 position: relative;
                 float: left;
             }                                       
        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
            
            
            <div id="mynetwork" class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
                
        <script type="text/javascript">

              // initialize global variables.
              var edges;
              var nodes;
              var allNodes;
              var allEdges;
              var nodeColors;
              var originalNodes;
              var network;
              var container;
              var options, data;
              var filter = {
                  item : '',
                  property : '',
                  value : []
              };
                            
              // This method is responsible for drawing the graph, returns the drawn network
              function drawGraph() {
                  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
                  
                  // parsing and collecting nodes and edges from the python
                  nodes = new vis.DataSet([{"color": "#97c2fc", "id": 0, "label": "A", "shape": "circle"}, {"color": "#97c2fc", "id": 1, "label": "B", "shape": "circle"}, {"color": "#97c2fc", "id": 2, "label": "C", "shape": "circle"}]);
                  edges = new vis.DataSet([{"from": 0, "title": "Pi-Pi Occupancy = 10%", "to": 1}, {"from": 1, "title": "Pi-Pi Occupancy = 10%", "to": 2}]);

                  nodeColors = {};
                  allNodes = nodes.get({ returnType: "Object" });
                  for (nodeId in allNodes) {
                    nodeColors[nodeId] = allNodes[nodeId].color;
                  }
                  allEdges = edges.get({ returnType: "Object" });
                  // adding nodes and edges to the graph
                  data = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};

                  var options = {
    "configure": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "edges": {
        "color": {
            "inherit": true
        },
        "smooth": {
            "enabled": true,
            "type": "dynamic"
        }
    },
    "interaction": {
        "dragNodes": true,
        "hideEdgesOnDrag": false,
        "hideNodesOnDrag": false
    },
    "physics": {
        "enabled": true,
        "stabilization": {
            "enabled": true,
            "fit": true,
            "iterations": 1000,
            "onlyDynamicEdges": false,
            "updateInterval": 50
        }
    }
};                                    
                  network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);                                                      
                  return network;

              }
              drawGraph();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following fixed the issue:

```
self.web.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
```

This allows the `QWebEngineWidget` to access online resources, which is disabled by default. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum